# How to repeat a formula every two rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

You help is greatly appreciated! I'm trying to repeat a formula from column K. I need it to repeat twice in column G and four times in column C. I've tried dragging two and four cells, but the sequence gets messed up by either 2 or 4 cells. Thanks in advance!

[image: Sheet Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In C2:

```
=OFFSET($K$1,QUOTIENT(ROW()+2,4),0)
```

In G2:

```
=OFFSET($K$1,QUOTIENT(ROW(),2),0)
```

Copy formulae down.